# Lync 2010, Group Chat deployment doubts

Tags: lync

We currently support Microsoft Lync 2010 infrastructure. We are considering deploying Group Chat in order to provide persistent chat.

1. Can not simply add the Group Chat services to the existing Lync 2010 Server, or does it require a separate server?
2. If adding Group Chat to our existing Lync Server is not supported, what is the simplest recommended method to upgrade our Lync environment to single 2013 server with Persistent Chat enabled?
3. If we upgrade to Lync 2013, do we have to get new licences for the accounts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can only answer the last question.  Yes;  If you upgrade you would have upgrade each of your account's license.

Comment: Enterprise Agreement – True-up Guide: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14452 Lync 2013 Licensing Guide: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/C/7/8C7C30DA-0386-4698-8BBB-367EAC8C4352/Lync%20Licensing%20Guide%20February%202013.pdf
 Lync 2013 Licensing Guide - How to licence Lync Server and Client: http://lyncuc.blogspot.ru/2013/02/lync-2013-licensing-guide-how-to.html

Comment: Step by Step Migration from Lync Server 2010 to Lync Server 2013 – Part 1: http://www.oiboran.com/?p=1073

Migration from Lync Server 2010 to Lync Server 2013: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205369(v=ocs.15).aspx

Step By Step Guide Microsoft Lync 2010 and Lync 2013 Server Pools Coexistence and Migration:  http://www.vmwareandme.com/2013/11/step-by-step-guide-microsoft-lync-2010.html

Lync 2010 to Lync 2013 Migration Guide: http://lyncdude.com/2013/09/23/lync-2010-to-lync-2013-migration-guide/

Answer (score 0):

According [this blog](http://www.mindlinksoft.com/blog/bid/64026/The-Skinny-on-Lync-2013-Microsoft-Lync-Group-Chat-done-right-well-almost) and [this forum](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Internet_Email/Chat_-_IM/Q_27379002.html), it seems that Group Chat cannot be installed in the same server where Lync Server is.
If somebody has more information about this, leave a comment please.